# Is there a way to split a face in cubes (but remaining as one mesh) ? (explode modifier ?)

Tags: modeling

I want to find a way to split the face of a character in separated cubes (but remaining as the same "face mesh" !), as if my character was a man made from stone for example.

I've tried to Ctrl-B on the desired faces, which gave me what I wanted (I also apply this modification to the arms and hands), but I was not able to scale the new faces inward the character (to create a bump effect), and I don't know if its possible.

[image]

Is there a way to do so ?
 - Could the explode modifier help me to reach this result ?
 - Or maybe the Ctrl-B shortcut ?

Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
The frontmost image has used inset, extrude, and some faces between extrusions have been deleted.

---

[image]
Select, Inset, Extrude Individual Faces which can create faces targeted for deletion if you like. Blue sphere shows inset before any extrusion.  Yellow edit mode is the extrusion. Image above.

---

[image]
Inset skipped.  Image Above

---

In Edit Mode

- Face Mode
- Make a selection of faces
- Inset Faces with the individual option ... See the tools keystrokes listed in the UI. Press <kbd>I</kbd> for individual inset [ON]
- Menu ... Extrude Individual Faces .  Be careful to use the new selection provided by the tool.  If you loose the selection then use [undo] to recover the selection
- Set the pivot for scaling to individual origins .. with the upper tool bar ... yellow arrow
- Scale ... to scale the selected faces to the center of each face
- Improve these steps

---

- Delete Faces if you like to create islands
- Know that you in edit mode you can add another shape such as a cube et cetera
- You can always join two different meshes into one mesh

Comment: Thanks a lot, usually I don't use this Inset function. In the end that was pretty simple and accurate. Thank you ! :)